# Is it possible to use Ninject without inheriting from NinjectHttpApplication?

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-2

I'd like to Ninject as the IOC container for my WebForms solution to achieve property injection, but the global.asax is already inheriting from another class so I cannot inherit from NinjectHttpApplication as well.

Does any one have any solutions as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current development version (2.3.0.x) comes with NuGet package using WebActivator that does not require to inherit from HttpApplication. You have to build it yourself though as it is work in progress.

Comment: Awesome, may just be what I'm after! Are there any examples on how to use the WebActivator?

Comment: No not at the moment. But there will be as soon as everything has been finished for the next release. So either you have to be patient and wait for the release or look at the code.